FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
I am using flutter below
Flutter 1.22.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d408d302e2 (3 years, 8 months ago) • 2020-09-29 11:49:17
-0700
Engine • revision 5babba6c4d
Tools • Dart 2.10.0

when I try to run application in android device, it's giving me following error

Here is my build.gradle file
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

and here is my top level build.gradle file
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.hr.neeti_employee"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {

            keyAlias 'hrneeti'
            keyPassword 'hrneeti2021'
            storeFile file('/Users/jeckymodi/Documents/Projects/HRNeeti repo/hrNeetiKeyStore/hrNeetiKeyStore.jks') //<-----file here
            storePassword 'hrneeti2021'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    /*splits {
        density {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "mdpi", "hdpi"
        }
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "x86", "x86_64"
        }
    }*/
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

